# NX Unable to resolve @nrwl/node:execute

Tags: node.js, npm, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Cannot find executor 'execute' in C:\Users\ssss\Desktop\code-base\node_modules@nrwl\node\executors.json.
Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace..
I upgraded to node v16.20.0 and upgraded nrwl/cli to 15.9.3. executors.json file is already there. how to fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.